# useContext can only be called from the build method of HookWidget

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am creating a simple single value program in Riverpod. There is a floating action button which on click increments the counter value.

Here's the `MyHomePage` widget:

```dart
final provider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) => CounterNotifier());

class MyHomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final counterModel = useProvider(provider.state);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Counter'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('You have pushed the button this many times'),
            Text('${counterModel.count}',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          context.read(provider).increment();
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and then running it as a Windows app.

[image]

Comment: This can happen if you change from a Stateless/Stateful/Consumer/etc. Widget to a HookWidget and don't restart your app.

Comment: @AlexHartford Yes that was the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When changing

```
class YourName extends StatelessWidget
```

to

```
class YourName extends HookWidget
```

you almost certainly need to stop your application and restart it typing

```
flutter run
```

in your console.

Answer (score 0):

For my case i was assigning the **useProvider()** method outside the **build method of a HookWidget**.

Comment: useProvider is removed, All hooks works within HookConsumerWidget. Including useFutureyou can see : https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/335